# Issue when trying to suspend pc from c#

Tags: c#, suspend

I have been using Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, false, false); to try and sleep the machine when a certain event is fired. However when this runs, the PC hibernates.

Any help here would be great! :)

Comment: Are you sure that the computer you're testing it on supports the "Suspend" power mode? Windows (seen it at least on 8.1) seems to default to hibernate if the suspend is not available.

Comment: Yeah. I can put it into the suspend power mode out of c# using the power off menu.